# system.nullReferenceException throwed, while starting a loop in a loop using arrays and dictionaries

Tags: arrays, vb.net, loops, exception, nullreferenceexception

i have another system.nullReferenceexcpetion. here is the code. the exception is thrown at the marked line. if needed i can give you the inizializing of the used arrays and dictionaries.

```
    public sub mappen()
    Dim feld(Form1.arr1.Length) As String



    For i As Integer = 0 To Form1.arr1.Length - 1


        feld(i) = Form1.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString


        ***For ix As Integer = 0 To Form1.Spaltennamen.Length - 1***

            Select Case feld(i)
                Case Form1.Spaltennamen(ix)
                    Form1.ComboauswahlD(Form1.Spaltennamen(ix)) = i
            End Select

        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

the method is in module1. spaltennamen is initilized in form1

here is the code

```
 Public Class Form1

 Public Spaltennamen() As String

     Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


    Dim table As New DataTable

    table = SkMTabelle.SLXADRIUMDEVDataSet.mappen

    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim Spaltennamen(table.Columns.Count) As String

    For Each column As DataColumn In table.Columns

        Spaltennamen(i) = column.ColumnName
        i = i + 1

    Next
```

Edit i found one bug at the form1 class. Spaltennamen is declared in the formloader and in the head of the class.

nevertheless the big bug cant be in the mappen() method because if take the procedur of form1 out, where i fill spaltennamen and instead fill spaltennamen in the code before runtime, everything works fine...

Comment: what is `Form1.Spaltennamen?` How and when is it initialized?

Comment: So `Form1` is a variable inside your module?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line that throws the exception and then hover the mouse over each identifier and you will find which one is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `Form1` with an instance of `Form1` as `Form1` is a `Type`.

**Example**

```
Dim f As New Form1()

feld(i) = f.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString
```

**Debug**

```
Public Class Form1

    Friend Spaltennamen() As String '= Nothing aka no instance created.

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        '- Here you got a contradiction. 
        '    1) First you create a new instance of a `DataTable`.
        '    2) Then you set it to what should have been a return value (DataTable) of `mappen`, 
        '       but it's a `Sub` and not a `Function`.
        Dim table As New DataTable
        table = SkMTabelle.SLXADRIUMDEVDataSet.mappen
        '                                        |
        '               --------------------------
        '               |
        '              \|/
        'Public Sub mappen()

            '- Form1 is a type, not an instance.
            '- For this to work, you could do one of the following suggestions:
            '    1) Move all code inside `mappen` and place it inside this method (as shown here) and replace `Form1` with `Me`.
            '    2) Change your method to accept an instance of Form1 `Public Sub mappen( f As Form1)`, change `Form1` to `f` and then
            '       just call `mappen(Me)`.
            '- Is `arr1` instantiated? `forminstance.arr1 = New Object(?-1){}` (Replace `Object` with correct data type)
            '- Arrays in vb.net use zero-base indexing. Here you create a `feld` array which can hold +1 more item
            '  than `arr1`.
            Dim feld(Form1.arr1.Length) As String
            For i As Integer = 0 To Form1.arr1.Length - 1
                '- Form1 is a type, not an instance.
                '- Are you sure `Rows(i)` exists?
                '- Are you sure you want the second column? Cells(1) <- Zero-base indexing makes this column 2.
                '  The first column have index `0`.
                feld(i) = Form1.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString
                For ix As Integer = 0 To Form1.Spaltennamen.Length - 1
                    Select Case feld(i)
                        '- Form1 is a type, not an instance.
                        '- Is Spaltennamen instantiated? `forminstance.Spaltennamen = New String(?-1){}` 
                        Case Form1.Spaltennamen(ix)
                            '- Form1 is a type, not an instance.
                            '- Is `ComboauswahlD` instantiated?  `forminstance.ComboauswahlD = New Object(?-1){}` (Replace `Object` with correct data type)
                            Form1.ComboauswahlD(Form1.Spaltennamen(ix)) = i
                    End Select
                Next
            Next
        'End Sub

        Dim i As Integer = 0
        '- In vb.net, if you specify a length of an array, it is instantiated. (Finally)
        '- Are you sure it should holde +1 more item than the number of columns?
        Dim Spaltennamen(table.Columns.Count) As String
        For Each column As DataColumn In table.Columns
            Spaltennamen(i) = column.ColumnName
            i = i + 1
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: So `Form1` is a variable inside your module?

Comment: no. spaltennamen is inizilized in form1. i added the code

Comment: @user3360700 Check my edit. Unless `arr1`, `DataGridView1` and `Spaltennamen` are declared `Shared` then you'll need an instance of `Form1`.

Comment: i checked the shared declaration. it didnt work. i get a exception that module1 sub .. cannot use the variables. with public i dont get it. When i iniziate a new instance of form 1 i get a "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException" at the line 
feld(i) = f.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString

Comment: @user3360700 Don't make them shared. I'm sorry to say but your code have _so many_ bugs that I don't know where to begin. I suggest you turn both `Strict On` and `Explicit On` (which is always recommended): http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311329 Also, if you replace `table = SkMTabelle.SLXADRIUMDEVDataSet.mappen` with everything inside `Public Sub mappen()` it's easier to picture the call stack.

Comment: no problem. i am thankfull for any input. it´s my first projekt after programming lessons at university. and the very first time i program in vb.net. i dont know what you mean with your second advice? table is a table of a bound ms sql database and mappen() is a method in which i want to map the columns of the sql database with the columns of a csv file.

Comment: @user3360700 Please see my edit where I've tried to point out all your errors.

Comment: forget to mention again. mappen() is a silent method and 
table = SkMTabelle.SLXADRIUMDEVDataSet.mappen is the link to the datatable called mappen im my sql database

Comment: well, one day later, with fresh konzentration, after 30 minutes all worked beter then before lol